# zend framework エラー　offsetGet

Tags: php, zend-framework

公開中のホームページのコンタクトフォームを表示するところで、以下のエラーが出てしまいました。どうしていいか見当がつかず困っています。

エラー内容

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject::offsetGet() must be compatible with that of ArrayAccess::offsetGet() in /usr/home/mw2pvmf59l/www/lib/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject.php on line 22
```

PHPバージョンはもともと5.4でしたが、現在は5.3です。
最近レンタルサーバー側で5.4, 5.5提供終了のアナウンスがありました。
現在は5.3か5.6を利用できます。

Answer (score 1):

ご利用のZendFrameworkのバージョンはいくつでしょうか？以下の方法で解決できるかもしれません。

英語になりますが、[コチラ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238617/php-fatal-error-declaration-of-zend-stdlib-arrayobjectoffsetget)のリンク先に詳細の解決方法があるので引用します。

ZendFramework2.3はPHP5.3.23かそれ以上が必要です。問題を解決するにはPHPを5.3.23かそれ以上にアップグレードする必要があります。
あるいは、何らかの理由によりアップグレードができない場合は、代わりにZendFrameworkを2.2.xにダウングレードする必要があります。

Comment: PHPのバージョンを5.3から5.6に変更したら、エラー無く動作するようになりました。回答いただいたとおり、ZF2.3でしたので、PHPのアップグレードで解決できました。
ありがとうございました。